# Is it necessary to use projected coordinate system for sf (function: st_nearest_feature) package?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, proximity, sf

I have two csv files, each with lat/long coordinates. I converted them into sf objects, giving each GCS (geographic coordinate system) crs. When I use the st_nearest_feature function, I get this warning:

```
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_nearest_feature assumes that they are planar
```

I'm just getting the index of the closest points and don't need the exact distance.

Are there any problems in not converting the coordinate systems ahead of time that I should be aware of?

Comment: The problem is the possibility of obtaining false results. A distance of one degree of latitude can be greater than a distance of two degrees of longitude.